# Spring @Autowired parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm having some difficulties trying to understand the `@Autowired` annotation in Spring.

As I understood until now, I can , under some circumstance, declare `@Autowired` on an instance variable if I declare this variable class in the xml file where I keep the beans.

Under these circumstances, as I understood, I don't have to instanciate beans as they will get injected automatically declared by Spring. What I didn't understand is:

- I can declare in the xml for example one or more DAO beans that gets a connection as a parameter, but if I have to make different DAO's operations (for example get the user asking for the user DAO and then make another operation with another DAO) using the same instance of the connection?
- What is the difference in setting the `@Autowired` annotation in the constructor or in the setter methods?

Comment: In my humble opinion : I have never declared a connection as parameter but always used the annotation `@Transactional` (which handles the whole transaction for you). I also even did not know that it was possible to use @Autowired on setter methods. I always used `@Autowired` on class attibutes and it always fitted my needs.

Answer (score 0):

To inject a connection object in your DAOs, all of those have to be spring beans (declared in the xml). By default, all spring beans are singletons so two different DAOs would share the same instance of connection.

About you second question, you have a third option, *@Autowired* on a field level. What you should use is subjective, but this [blog](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/why-i-changed-my-mind-about-field-injection/) post explains the differences rather well, it cross links a lot of other posts on the subject

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it now. Talking about first question I obviously don't want my connection to be a singleton class so I don't think I can proceed this way.

Comment: You welcom. Speaking about singleton, its always a matter of requirement and design, but generally speaking, making a connection object a singleton is considered a good practice. A typical implementation without the use of frameworks is explained here http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jdbc/jdbc-examples-introduction/#Design_Patterns_Used. Spring complements it nicely by loosing coupling through dependency injection

Comment: Just as a small addition: Pivotal does not recommend field injection in their official training courses (Spring CORE) as it makes unit testing harder. So either use method injection (on the setters) or constructor injection. Here an interesting article by Oliver Gierke: http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/